# Bandwidth limit by Port on iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables

What `iptables` function would I use to bandwidth-limit all traffic on port 566 to 2KB/s?

I'm confused about exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You would normally use "tc" (traffic control) for this.

See here the [Traffic Control HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html).