# How to share bandwidth among different applications?

Tags: linux, bandwidth

Suppose i am running git clone in my terminal and downloading something via firefox, if I would like to limit the bandwidth usage for one of the applications and increase more for another, is there a way to do it in linux ? Firefox and git clone are just examples that i have given here. I would like an application agnostic method to do from operating system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bandwidth limit by Port on iptables](http://superuser.com/questions/644513/bandwidth-limit-by-port-on-iptables)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool dedicated to this : trickle.

Usage : `trickle -d <download-limit-in-kbps> -u <upload-limit-in-kbps> <command>` and it will 'shape' your command with those limits.

It works for most command, but it does not work for me with a 'git clone'.